# Need to update some JLabels inside a loop

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlabel

I call the next void from another void when I have to delete some JTable rows.
So, in the main void, I have a loop to search for a set of rows to delete. When the loop finds one, the next void is called to delete the desired rows.

Something like this:

```
* from another void:

    Begin loop {
        is there some rows to delete ?
        if yes, call aplica_super_reducao()
        if no, the loop goes on
    {

private void aplica_super_reducao(Integer [] num_filtros,Integer qualidade) {
    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel)desdobramentos.getModel();
    int chave_sim = 0;
    Integer reduz=0;
    Integer cal_tot=0;
    Integer cal_red=0;
    //Percorre todas as chaves desdobradas
    for (int a = 0; a < modelo.getRowCount(); a++) {
          int n1 = (Integer) modelo.getValueAt(a, 0);
          int n2 = (Integer) modelo.getValueAt(a, 1);
          int n3 = (Integer) modelo.getValueAt(a, 2);
          int n4 = (Integer) modelo.getValueAt(a, 3);
          int n5 = (Integer) modelo.getValueAt(a, 4);
              //Percorre todos os números do cada filtro
              for (int i = 0; i < qualidade; i++) {
                   Integer z = num_filtros[i];
                   if (n1 == z ) {chave_sim=chave_sim+1;}
                   if (n2 == z ) {chave_sim=chave_sim+1;}
                   if (n3 == z ) {chave_sim=chave_sim+1;}
                   if (n4 == z ) {chave_sim=chave_sim+1;}
                   if (n5 == z ) {chave_sim=chave_sim+1;}
               }   
               if (chave_sim == 5) {
                  // APAGAR ESTA CHAVE DA TABELA
                  modelo.removeRow(a);
                  a=a-1;
                  chave_sim=0;
               }
     }
    tot_apos_filtros.setText(Integer.toString(modelo.getRowCount())) ;
    cal_red=modelo.getRowCount();
    cal_tot=Integer.parseInt(tot_desdobra.getText()); 
    reduz=cal_red*100/cal_tot;
    reduz=100-reduz;
    per_reducao.setText(Integer.toString(reduz)+" %") ;
}
```

As you can see, I need to update some JLabels when the process ends (when all rows are deleted). But, because this void is called from a working loop, these JLabels are only updated when the main loop ends.

Because this a long process (several minutes), I would like to see these JLabels updated regulary.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Start with [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). The problem is, the `TableModel` itself is connected to the UI, so you can't modify from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. You could use a `SwingWorker` to loop over the model and `publish` the rows you want deleted - or better yet, build a new `TableModel` which is returned at the end of th processing. Either way, `SwingWorker` support progress notification

Comment: The TableModel could be updated just after the loop. The Important are the JLabels that keeps the user informed about the progress